# Select keyframe closest to a particular instant with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, keyframe

I have an MP4 video created by some third party software. I am not aware if the keyframes are at regular intervals or not. I have been successful in extracting a video frame corresponding to the 3rd minute (180 seconds * frames/s) with FFMPEG.

What I want to do is extract the "closest" keyframe to the third minute - since it is often the case that the frame that I extract with the currently successful code is NOT a keyframe and therefore blurry.

I know there is a way to extract *all* keyframes in FFMPEG, but is there a way to extract the keyframe closest to a particular time in a video?

Comment: A variation of the above question is - if I have several frames (images), is there a way to programmatically identify which is a key frame?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [select filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect) to pick an "I" frame (aka a key frame).

```
 ffmpeg -ss 3:00 -i "my_video.mkv" -map 0:v:0 -filter:v "select=eq(pict_type\,I)" -vframes 1  3_min.jpg
```

In the above example we are FFmpeg to:

- go to the three minute mark of the next input `-ss 3:00`
- define the input `-i "my_video.mkv"`
- select from the first input : a video track : specifically the first one `-map 0:v:0`
- use the magic select filter on the video `-filter:v "select=eq(pict_type\,I)"`
- only grab a single frame from the movie `-vframes 1`
- define where to save the image, and what format (can change to `.bmp`, `.png`, etc...) `3_min.jpg`